# PyQt - How to link specific dialog with class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I have created a PyQt MainWindow app and I have also created 2 PyQt dialogs in PyQt designer, then a "calling" .pyw program, problem is that when I try open the different dialogs, it only opens one dialog.

how do I explicitly set/link a dialog to a class:

```
import sys
from MainApp import *
from Dialog1 import *
from Dialog2 import *
from PyQt4 import Qt, QtGui


class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton1, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.openDialog1)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton2, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.openDialog2)    


    def openDialog1(self):
        editDialog = Dialog1()
        editDialog.exec_()

    def openDialog2(self):
        editDialog = Dialog2()
        editDialog.exec_()        



class Dialog1(QtGui.QDialog):
    isEdit = False
    def __init__(self, studentId=0, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

class Dialog2(QtGui.QDialog):
    isEdit = False
    def __init__(self, studentId=0, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Be default it loads Dialog2, If I comment out this line:

```
from Dialog2 import **
```

Then it loads Dialog1,  I want to explicitly set which dialog it loads

[Github link](https://github.com/chatschang/PyQtTest)

Comment: What do you mean they open the same dialogues? Are the Ui_Dialog() in EditStudentDialog and EditAttendanceDialog the same?

Comment: Problems of the type: "why my code not working?" must provide a [mcve] but become off-topic and your code is far from being verifiable and complete.

Comment: You could provide a project that can be executed, your current code can be interpreted by many ways, it would be great to share that minimal project through github or similar to test it and not waste time trying to patch your code.

Comment: I have updated question to be more readable and understanding, also added a Github link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import:

```
from Dialog1 import *
from Dialog2 import *
```

It is equivalent to:

```
from Dialog1 import Ui_Dialog
from Dialog2 import Ui_Dialog
```

so in the end `Ui_Dialog` will refer to the design of `Dialog2.py` and that's the reason why only the second form is shown.

The solution is to differentiate both imports and for this you can use: `as`

```
import sys
from MainApp import *
from Dialog1 import Ui_Dialog as Ui_Dialog1 # change this line
from Dialog2 import Ui_Dialog as Ui_Dialog2 # change this line
from PyQt4 import Qt, QtGui


class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        [...]


    def openDialog1(self):
        editDialog = Dialog1()
        editDialog.exec_()

    def openDialog2(self):
        editDialog = Dialog2()
        editDialog.exec_()


class Dialog1(QtGui.QDialog):
    isEdit = False
    def __init__(self, studentId=0, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog1() # change this line
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

class Dialog2(QtGui.QDialog):
    isEdit = False
    def __init__(self, studentId=0, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog2() # change this line
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```